# SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'weee_tax' already exists, query was

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

Myself try to upgrade the magento version 1.9.1 to 1.9.2.2

refer the link :http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/upgrade-with-connect-manager

after delete the maintenance.flag file 
facing this kind off error in front-end

```
Error in file: "/home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Weee/sql/weee_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table **'weee_tax'** already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE `weee_tax` (
```

Please share me , how to resolved this error.

Comment: did the upgrading process ran successfully?or did it resulted any error?

Comment: s upgrade is successfully .. no...
In root ,Rename the Wee_setup folder then its working fine..@Krish

Answer (score 0):

core config table has version number for each module installed.

You need to check that value there is right.As if by mistake a lower version of that is in place for the moduel min question then  Magento will execute queries of higher version.

This has resulted in a create query getting executed and so the error.